# Why magento shows cart when a product is added to cart

Tags: cart

It is just crazy that magento shows the cart when a product is added to the cart. I didn't do anything it just started acting like this by itself. weird.

How do I unset this? I don't want the items in the cart to be displayed when i add a product to the cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a config setting, you can change this behaviour here:

```
System > Configuration > Checkout > Shopping Cart > After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart
```

Comment: Thanks! It is just weird it was set to enabled by itself! Didn't do anything